# Derivative of $P=(\frac{OCV}{Ri+Ru}^2*Ru)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find out with what Ru, $P= (\frac{OCV}{R_i+R_u})^2*R_u$ has a max value,where OCV is a constant. I have no experience doing multivariable derivatives yet. I have looked up some information about it online but having some guidelines or a answer would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take a multivariable derivative you simply hold all other variables constant, in this case that's $R_i$. Doing that we can find that
$$\frac {\partial P}{\partial R_u}=\left(\frac {OCV}{R_i + R_u}\right)^2\left (1-2\frac {R_u}{R_u + R_i}\right)=0$$
Which is of course the case when $R_u = R_i$ (it is also undefined when $R_u = -R_i$ which is important to consider). So that's the $R_u$ that would be a critical point for $P$ assuming $R_i $ to be constant.
Note however, that doesn't necessarily mean that's when $P $ has an extrema. Not only do you have to check whether that's a maximum (which gets a lot more complicated with more variables), you would also have to take $\frac {\partial P}{\partial R_i}$ and solve the system
$$\frac {\partial P}{\partial R_i}=0$$
$$\frac {\partial P}{\partial R_u}=0$$
To find critical points for $P $ taking into account both variables.

Comment: Thanks, i understand. $R_i = R_u$ is what i needed and that makes sense in context of my project.

Comment: Also make sure that you consider $R_u=-R_i $ because undefined points are also critical points. (Also to check if that's a maximum, which I didn't do, just take the second partial derivative of P with respect to $R_u $ and check like normal. Just treat $R_i$ as a constant.